# How to get C# (.net core) project directory path in Visual Studio 2017 RC3?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have a C# (.Net Core) solution in visual studio 2017 RC3 that contains many projects (4 if you are curious) and that I recently migrated from the old project.json/visual studio 2015 format by using VS 2017 RC3.

One of the projects is a test project, in which I need to access some files contained under it.

It seems that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` cannot be relied upon to get the projects path in the test code, since tests , in VS 2017, are ran from the IDE's installation location  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE`.

Currently I am working around this by hard-coding the test project's base path. As this is not ideal, **is there an alternative to programatically get the base path of a project in VS 2017 RC3?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want with AppContext.BaseDirectory. This will return where the tests are running from %projectfolder%\bin\debug\netcoreapp1.1. You could do something like this to get the project folder.

`AppContext.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppContext.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin"));`

You could throw this into a helper or extension method.

Comment: I would use `LastIndexOf` in case any preceding directory has the sequence "bin" in it.

Answer (score 6):

Following on Matthew's answer, I ended up with this code (VSCode/.net-core/C#/MacOSX) to get the actual *solution root* versus the *project root*:

```
var appRoot = AppContext.BaseDirectory.Substring(0,AppContext.BaseDirectory.LastIndexOf("/bin"));
appRoot = appRoot.Substring(0,appRoot.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

The `+1` bit allows you to include the trailing forward slash.